# In Rails how to store an active record temporarily only for that specific session?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a shopping cart model. When someone clicks `Add to cart` I want to create a record in the database only if the user is signed in. If there's no signed-in user, I want to store this in a temporary storage which will get deleted when the user closes the browser. The reason is, even a not signed in user can checkout as a guest. How can I do this? Is there a way to do this using something like `redis`?

Comment: You can follow this link.https://github.com/rails/activerecord-session_store.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you may use ActiveRecord for such users, too, and erase carts with user_id equal to nil every, say, 2 hours. The benefit of this approach is that you shouldn't process carts for sign-in and not sign-in users differently (I mean, fetch them from different sources, store them in different ways, ensure they are consistent).

Just create cart:

```
cart = Cart.find(session[:cart_id]) if session[:cart_id]
if cart.blank?
  cart = Cart.create(user: current_user)
  session[:cart_id] = cart.id
end
```

And then sweep them it with cron (via `whenever` gem):

```
every 2.hours do
  rake "carts:sweep_inactive"
end
```

Comment: Yep it might be the best way. But the problem is, how to tie the guest use with the cart? If he want to add another item to the cart, how to track him and add to the same cart?

Comment: Sorry, forget to add cart_id to session, I'll edit the answer

Comment: Just edited. Now cart for current_user (even non-signed in) is stored in session and can be fetched. As far as I know, storing information in session is secure (a user can't access to other's carts).